# Should this be optimized?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

This is a servlet that will run on Tomcat 7.0. The application is pretty busy.

What we have done is the following:

```
public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //get the path {/api/login}
    String requestPath = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().indexOf(getServletConfig().getServletContext().getContextPath()) + getServletConfig().getServletContext().getContextPath().length());
    //get the responder class {mobi.foo.base.api.login}
    Class<? extends Responder> responderClass = Class.forName("mobi.foo.base"+requestPath.replaceAll("/", ".")).asSubclass(Responder.class);
    //initialize a responder using reflection
    Responder responder = responderClass.newInstance();

    //print the response
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(responder.respond());
    out.close();
}
```

So on the first occasion, I was inclined to accept this since it does not count to the bottleneck. In other words, even if this is relatively slow, its convenience outweighs the rather insignificant overhead it introduces: We are talking about an http request that will probably access a database!

Am I right? I just want to know others' view on this.

Comment: Do you have a performance problem? Have you proven that this performance problem came from this piece of code? If you answer no to any of these questions, you should not optimize. That said, it seems you're reinventing an action-based framework. Why don't you use a real one? Or simply use several servlets mapped to URLs? This potentially causes security problems: it allows anyone to make the server load any class in mobi.foo.base*.

Answer (score 2):

Q: Should it be optimized?

A: Use a profiler to measure the percentage time spent in the code of concern.  If the percentage of time is significant, then optimize it.  Otherwise don't.

Of course, we can't give you a definite quantification of "significant".  It actually depends on what the actual costs are.  For instance, if you have one instance of the webapp and it is lightly loaded most of the time, then a 1% increase in performance would most likely not be worthwhile.  On the other hand if you had thousands of copies of this program flat out running on thousands of servers, then a 1% increase in performance might be worthwhile ... just in the reduction to your electricity bills.

---

Can it be optimized?

I think that it is unlikely that you will much speedup.  Replacing the `class.forName` and `newInstance()` with a `HashMap` lookup of a factory object, etcetera might save some fraction of a micro-second per call<sup>1</sup>.  That *might* amount to a significant speedup ... but I doubt it.

However I think @JBNizet is making an important point.  There is a potential security concern here.  Addressing *that issue* would be a sound reason for overhauling this code.

---

<sup>1 - The cost of loading classes gets amortized as request types are repeated.  When you call `class.forName` for a class that has previously been loaded, the classloaders simply look up and return an existing `Class` object.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If your respond() method use only method variables (not class fields) you can create the Responder and put it in a pool of responders and reuse it without creating it each time.

basically something like that:

```
//get the path {/api/login}
String requestPath = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().indexOf(getServletConfig().getServletContext().getContextPath()) + getServletConfig().getServletContext().getContextPath().length());
//get the responder class {mobi.foo.base.api.login}

String responderName = "mobi.foo.base"+requestPath.replaceAll("/", ".");

Responder responder = responderMap.get(responderName);
if (responder == null) {
    Class<? extends Responder> responderClass = Class.forName("mobi.foo.base"+requestPath.replaceAll("/", ".")).asSubclass(Responder.class);
    //initialize a responder using reflection
    Responder responder = responderClass.newInstance();
    responderMap.put(responderName, responder);
}


//print the response
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.write(responder.respond());
out.close();
```

where responderMap is map of type `Map<String, Responder>` saved in ServletContext or available as a singleton.